# Automatized tool to test site via browser?

Tags: testing

does anybody knows a tool when I can set a scenario (click here, fill this form, submit) just like a human did it? Preferably with Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can test site by using selenium. Its a automated testing tool.Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin.So you can use that

Comment: you can take help from here  http://qtpselenium.com/selenium-training/selenium-tutorial/selenium-training-java-part-1